# Conference Calls in Skype using android application

Tags: android, skype

I am trying to make a skype call via my application. I am successful via this code snippet

```
        Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("skype:" + "skypeName" + "?call"));
        skypeIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
        skypeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(skypeIntent);
```

The above code is able to do the skype call for only 1 user. But how can I achieve to make a conference calls?
I have googled and found that we need to use ";" to make a conference call but its only creating a group without making a call.

Please guide me through

Thanks

Comment: Use Linphone instead of Skype! it supports conference calls as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Reference says that you can't begin group calls in the Android version of Skype. I have no idea why.

> Mobile Skype clients (iOS and Android) do not support initiating/hosting conference calls.

[Skype URI API Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn745882.aspx)